# How to fix Python 3 PyAutoGUI screenshot error? (macOS)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, crash, screenshot, pyautogui

I keep getting an error with any of PyAutoGUI's screenshot taking functions such as:

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('button.png')
pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(x, y, (r, g, b))
im = pyautogui.screenshot()
```

The error I get is:

```
screencapture: cannot write file to intended destination, .screenshot2018-1009_16-43-26-003190.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/program.py", line 111, in <module>
    pyautogui.locateOnScreen('/images/play!.png')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 265, in locateOnScreen
    screenshotIm = screenshot(region=None) # the locateAll() function must handle cropping to return accurate coordinates, so don't pass a region here.
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 331, in _screenshot_osx
    im = Image.open(tmpFilename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2609, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.screenshot2018-1009_16-43-26-003190.png'
```

I don't tell it to or want it to save the new screenshotted image to any directory (and it shouldn't). With the pyautogui.screenshot() function I could manually save it to a real directory in my project, but I don't have an option to do that with the other methods. Any idea on how to fix this?

What I've tried:

- I looked at all the documentation I could find online of pyautogui screenshots
- Restarting computer
- Downgrading versions for Pillow and pyscreeze

EDIT:
I tried it on another mac and got the same error.
Tried it on windows bootcamp (windows on my mac) and it works fine.

Comment: Same issue here.. did you find an answer?

Comment: @Otto Sadly I have not. I have to do this kind of programming on Windows. I wonder if lots of mac users are having this problem as I have tried it on a different mac and still got the error. I'm guessing it's a bug that'll get fixed in the future. Best of wishes!

Comment: which version of osx were you using?  This was working for High Sierra but broke once I upgraded to Mojave.  Mojave had some screen capture changes so I wonder if that's related.

Comment: @RichardW Yeah, all the mac computers I've tested it on have been on the Mojave software. That must be it, good insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible, very hack-ish fix - I don't actually like this answer but it was a quick and easy fix (done on OSX with Mojave):

PLEASE NOTE: modifying the source code of libraries you don't understand is usually a bad idea, so do so at your own risk!  This worked for me, your milage may vary.

Go to your file (your file path may be different, I just copied this from your error):

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py
```

find the line under the function "_screenshot_osx" that looks like

```
tmpFilename = '.screenshot%s.png' % (datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m%d_%H-%M-%S-%f'))
```

copy it and then comment it out, paste the copied line directly below the commented out original and modify to something like this:

```
tmpFilename = r'<your preferred screenshot folder here>/screenshot%s.png' % (datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m%d_%H-%M-%S-%f'))
```

save the changes, and see if it works.

Also note: pyautogui.locateOnScreen can be a bit finicky so even if this removes your error you still might not get the coordinates you want (might return none).  That might be related to a different issue.  To test that part I do this:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.screenshot('testFull.png')
placePos = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('testFull.png')
print(placePos)
```

even the cursor blinking can mess this up though, and osx has translucent user interfaces so it's kind of annoying to test this perfectly without careful image curation.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue on MacOS Mojave after changing to Python 3.8.
Here is my solution.
Go the same file mentioned by @Richard W.
There, together with all your 'imports', add the following line so the script can find the *tmpFilename* folder

```
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

then, replace the also mentioned line by

```
tmpFilename = os.path.join(dirname,r'screenshot%s.png' % (datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m%d_%H-%M-%S-%f')))
```